# Data being copied in 2 arrays

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So I'm trying to create a simple program that copies the inserted data into an array:

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data
    i db 0
    j db 0
    first db 0 dup(9)
    last db 0 dup(9)

.code
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
Loop1:    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    mov bl, i
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0

    mov first[bx], al
    add i, 1
    jmp Loop1
```

However when I run the program and check the status of the variables the data is being automatically copied into the array 'last' as well even though there hasn't been any code that tells the program to do so.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want `9 dup (0)`, not the other way around. Also, your loop is infinite.

Comment: Most of your loop is wasted instructions.  Just keep a counter or pointer in a register instead of storing/reloading and redoing zero-extension every iteration.  There's also no point in setting AH to 1 and 0 alternately.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> first db 0 dup(9)
> last db 0 dup(9)
> ```

The observation "...the data is being automatically copied into the array 'last' as well even though there hasn't been any code that tells the program to do so." is correct because you've actually placed both labels *first* and *last* at the same spot.

When you use the `dup` operator in order to obtain multiple copies of some datum, you must specify the count **before** the `dup` operator and the value(s) to be repeated between the parenthesis.

```
first db 9 dup (0)
last  db 9 dup (0)
```

This produces the following result that leaves room for 9 input bytes:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
^                          ^
first
                           last
```

With a count of 2 you would get:

```
0, 0, 0, 0
^     ^
first
      last
```

With a count of 1 you would get:

```
0, 0
^  ^
first
   last
```

But with the erroneous 0 as the count you got:

```
?
^
first
last
```

and therefore writing to `first[bx]` also wrote to `last[bx]`.

---

### You don't want to input more than the buffer can load!

> ```
> Loop1:
>     ...
>     jmp Loop1
> ```

Your present code constitutes an infinite loop.
Given that the input buffer has room for 9 bytes, you need to limit the number of iterations to that many. Use a counter variable like `mov cx, 9` that you decrement with each iteration and when it reaches 0 you stop the loop.

```
    mov cx, 9
Loop1:    
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov bl, i
    mov bh, 0
    mov first[bx], al
    add i, 1
    dec cx
    jnz Loop1
```

An optimized way of doing this brings the counter and the offset address together in a single register. You have a choice between `BX`, `SI`, and `DI`. There's also `BP` but then you would have to tinker with the segment registers. Don't know if you're up to that!

```
    xor bx, bx
Loop1:    
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov first[bx], al
    inc bx
    cmp bx, 9
    jb  Loop1
```

As you can see there was no real need to use a memory based index variable *i*.